# How to convert Sql query to codeigniter Active Record

Tags: codeigniter

I have sql query as below, i need to convert sql to codeigniter active record.

```
select * from color c 
    left join (select pc.* from product_color pc
        LEFT join product p on pc.product_id=p.product_id
        WHERE p.product_id=1)x on c.id=x.color_id
```

Comment: Please share your try ?

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter you can get compiled query using [get_compiled_select](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) function.

Let's create inner query first.

```
     $inner_query = $this->db->select('pc.*')
     ->from('product_color pc')
     ->join('product p','pc.product_id = p.product_id','left')
     ->where('p.product_id',1)
     ->get_compiled_select();
```

Now we will use inner query to create our final query.

```
 $final_query = $this->db->select('*')
 ->from('color c')
 ->join("($inner_query) x",'c.id=x.color_id','left')
  ->get_compiled_select();
echo $final_query; die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this into model file. and it's always better to keep sql keywords in capital.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM color c 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT pc.* FROM product_color pc
        LEFT JOIN product p ON pc.product_id=p.product_id
        WHERE p.product_id=1)x on c.id=x.color_id"

    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    $data =  $query->result_array();
```